# Trouble with linked-list recursive copy constructor

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm having difficulty figuring out what's wrong with my recursive copy constructor.

My class is a regular unsorted dynamic linked-list.

```
struct Node{
    int info;
    Node *next;
};
```

The following is just a simply way to look at the logic I'm going with

```
class Class{
public:
    //constructor
    Class(){ data = NULL;}

    //copy consturctor
    Class(const Class& second){
        cout << "This is copy constructor" << endl;



        //recursive copy contructor
        Class temp;
        temp.data = second.data;

        if (temp.data == NULL)  return; //base condition
        int x = temp.data->info;
        temp.data = second.data->next;
        insert(x);
        Class::Class(temp);

        //regular copy constructor
        /*if (second.data == NULL){//empty
        data = NULL;
        return;
        }
        Node *temp = second.data;
        Node *location = new Node;
        location->info = temp->info;
        data = location;
        location->next = NULL;
        temp = temp->next;

        while (temp != NULL){
        location->next = new Node;
        location = location->next;
        location->next = NULL;
        location->info = temp->info;
        temp = temp->next;
        }*/

    }   

    //destructor
    ~Class(){
        cout << "This is destructor" << endl;

        //recursive destructor
        /*Node *temp;
        temp = data;
        if (temp == NULL) return;
        else{
        data = data->next;
        delete temp;
        Class::~Class();
        }*/

        //reglar destructor
        Node *temp = data;
        while (data != NULL){
            temp = data;
            data = data->next;
            delete temp;
        }   
    }
    void insert(int x){
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp->info = x;
        temp->next = data;
        data = temp;
    }
    void print(){
        Node *temp = data;
        while (temp != NULL){
            cout << temp->info;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

private:
    Node *data;
};
```

And the main function:

```
void main(){

    Class object;

    object.insert(1);
    object.insert(2);
    object.insert(3);
    object.insert(4);
    object.print();

    Class object2 = object;
    object2.print();
}
```

Okay, so from my "many" experiments, it seems that the problem comes in when the recursion is done and the processing starts going backwards. So if this is 2 nodes, the 3rd one is NULL. The recursion is done, because of the

```
if (temp == NULL) return;
```

The destructor is called each time one stack is done, the first call to the destructor is that of the NULL object (the 3rd and latest one) which goes fine. The next call to the destructor is where trouble starts. It seems that the data passed to the destructor have garbage value.

Thing is, everything in the copy constructor is going fine, as in data are properly extracted and inserted. Why is the destructor having trouble?

Note: There is a recursive destructor (commented out) and a regular one. They both work fine but I'm using the regular one in case of unforeseen contingencies.

I've also included and commented out the regular copy constructor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a hint.  Don't do that.  If you really want to do it, don't recursively call the copy constructor.  Instead you can use a recursive helper function called from the copy constructor.  Copy constructors are special and the way you are using it won't work.

Comment: I know, it seems stupid to me as well, but it is part of my hw.

Comment: Do as I suggested.  Use a helper function.

Comment: It was my first intuition but thought he might not like it, meh whatever. Thanks.